# Why are React hooks named in this fashion useXXX?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have been wondering about the naming of the React hooks. For example useEffect, how does the name suggests something like componentDidUpdate or componentDidMount, which it is equivalent to? And these actions that we do after a component is loaded are not side-effects but are part of the main application flow, then why are these called side-effects?

Comment: And in case you are wondering: **"why is `useState` not named `createState` instead?"**

`“Create” wouldn’t be quite accurate because the state is only created the first time our component renders. During the next renders, useState gives us the current state. Otherwise it wouldn’t be “state” at all! There’s also a reason why Hook names always start with use. We’ll learn why later in the Rules of Hooks.`


https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#declaring-a-state-variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why are React hooks named in this fashion useXXX?

From the hooks docs, [Using a Custom Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#using-a-custom-hook)

> **Do I have to name my custom Hooks starting with “use”?** Please do. This
>   convention is very important. Without it, we wouldn’t be able to
>   automatically check for violations of rules of Hooks because we
>   couldn’t tell if a certain function contains calls to Hooks inside of
>   it.

The `use` prefix isn't indicating specific functionality other than that it is a react hook that React has established as a naming convention. This is similar to the HOC naming convention of using the `withXXXX` prefix.

> why are these called side-effects?

The `useEffect` hook is used to trigger an effect when a certain condition it met, in this case, when a value in its dependency array is updated. It is synonymous to the class-based component's lifecycle functions, the two most common ones being `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`.

The react state model is thought of as using pure functions to update state, i.e. `setState`/`useState`/etc which takes inputs, doesn't mutate them but instead returns a **new** object, whereas other functions, like `useEffect` don't directly mutate and return objects, but can issue other effects, such as calling asynchronous API endpoints, etc..

A super easy example using arrays

- `array::map` is a pure function that iterates over an array, maps each element to a new value, and returns a new array. No side-effect. (A redux reducer is similar by returning the next state value)
- `array::forEach` is a pure function that iterates over an array, calls a side-effect callback for each element, and returns `undefined`. Side-effect. (Calling an API, usually no return value, but triggers an update elsewhere)

Answer (score 2):

In Functional Programming paradigm when ever the function does something which changes something out of its environment then its called sideEffect.

In react a component's job is to just give a View about how the ui should look like. But for that we might require some other data rather than just props. eg: through network request. And when ever we are doing anything other than just returning the views like attaching event listeners etc those are sideEffects.